# Choosing between command line or menu in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm attempting to create a script that converts either a decimal, octal or hexadecimal number into binary.

I cannot use the bc command so I have create a function for each of these. I have a menu that allows you to select what number you wish the convert. e.g 1 for decimal, 2 for octal and 3 for hex.

I want to be able to also have a command line option so that:
    test.sh D 45 would convert 45 in decimal to binary,
    test.sh O 12 would convert 12 in octal to binary,
    test.sh H 0x1A would convert 0x1A in hexadecimal to binary

Is there a way to only use the menu if there are no command line arguments?

Comment: Use an `if` statement, of course. What's the problem?

Comment: Check the number of arguments, if it's equal to 3 (prog name + Letter + Number) proceed with one way, if not, use the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then 
    # Get parameters from arguments
else
    # Get parameters with menu
fi
# Calculate the result
```